# PowerShell HTML method getElementsByClassName returns null

Tags: html, powershell, dom

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script which fetches an HTML page from a website and extracts some information from it.

My code looks like this:

```
$html = (invoke-webrequest -uri $address).parsedHTML;
$bodyHTML = $html.body.getElementsByClassName("news-item")[0].innerText;
```

The script fetches the website fine. The important part of the website looks like this:

```
...
<DIV class=news-item>
Important Information
...
```

The Problem:
I always get an error message: "cannot index into a null array".
The getElementsByClassName()-Function does not return anything.

If I list all div's and show the class names:

```
$html.body.getElementsByTagName("div") | select className
```

it lists all the class names including "news-item", which I am looking for.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the PowerShell version used. The PowerShell version running on the machine was 4.11.

With PowerShell 5.1 on a different machine the code worked fine.

As a workaround, because PowerShell coult not be updated and I was only looking for div-elements, I used the following code:

```
$bodyHTML = ($html.body.getElementsByTagName("div") | where { $_.className -eq "news-item" })[0].innerText;
```